# OpenGL matrix math utilities for Python?

Tags: python, opengl, matrix

Are there any Python libraries available for OpenGL-specific/compatible matrix math on 4x4 matrices?

I need about the feature set offered by Android's [android.opengl.Matrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/Matrix.html) class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [numpy](https://numpy.org/) to generate data that is compatible with OpenGL. Many of the [PyOpenGL](https://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/) calls can take numpy data structures directly (assuming it's the correct type). Additionally, numpy arrays are typically well arranged in memory, and so you can do what you want with the data (and it's easy to check *how* they are arranged).

Comment: Of course (and I'm already doing that), but numpy doesn't provide me functions for rotation/projection/scaling/etc, or quaternion rotation utilities.

Comment: [This module](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/transformations.py.html) is designed for that purpose. He has also written an [optimised C version](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/transformations.c.html). I have no experience of this module so YMMV.

Comment: That module doesn't look like it takes into account the column-major (OpenGL, FORTRAN) / row-major (NumPy, C) distinction.  Am I just not seeing it?

Comment: [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) is the best I use it in some of my [ModernGL](https://github.com/cprogrammer1994/ModernGL) examples.

Answer (score 9):

I created the library [Pyrr](https://github.com/adamlwgriffiths/Pyrr) to provide all the maths features you need for Core OpenGL.
It features matrices, vectors and quaternions and basic support for other primitives (rectangles, rays, lines, etc).

It has both a procedural API and, more recently, an Object Oriented API which is very powerful.

It's available on PyPi `pip install pyrr` and from the github link above.

Feedback, issues and new features are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

[PyGLM](https://pypi.org/project/PyGLM/) might be something to look at as well. The author claims to be 2x to 10x as fast as numpy.
It is based on the popular [OpenGL Mathematics](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/index.html), C++ header only, library.

Answer (score -1):

If you already know what you want in OpenGL, why not use [PyOpenGL](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/)? I believe all the functionality you want should be there, and [here are some docs on doing matrix transformations](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/context/numeric_arrays.html) and interfacing with NumPy.

Comment: I'm using PyOpenGL, but it doesn't have the utility functions I need.